# Counting specific letters within an array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am asked to create a function in which it counts all the leters from b-s within a string. Here is what i have so far:

```
def strange_count(s):
    count = 0
    s = s.lower()
    s_count = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s]
    while count <= len(s):
        for i in range(len(s_count)):
            if s_count[i] == s[count]:
                count += 1
    return
```

It is returning an error, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
  File "", line 4, in strange_count
    s_count = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s]
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you need to worry about upper case letters? What about foreign-language letters with diacritics like "é"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
s_count = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s]
```

should be like this:

```
s_count = ["b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s"]
```

Then you'll find that you're in an infinite loop, so try rewriting like this:

```
def strange_count(s):
  count   = 0
  s       = s.lower()
  s_count = ["b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s"]
  for letter in s:
    if letter in s_count:
      count += 1
  return count

print(strange_count("asfdsjfdlkwjrwoiureaoifhwabrejwer"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making a list, you can use the fact that letters sort lexicographically so you can compare them with `>` and `<`

```
def strange_count(s):
    total = 0
    for letter in s:
        if letter >= 'b' and letter <= 's':
            total += 1
    return total
```

For example

```
>>> strange_count('dictionary')
7
```

Or more compactly using a generator expression

```
def strange_count(s):
    return sum(1 for i in s if i >= 'b' and i <= 's')
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem - Variables *vs* Letters

```
s_count = [b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s]
```

The above is **not** declaring a list with elements that corresponds to the range of letters you are talking about.

What you are really saying is that `s_count` should be a *list* where the elements shall have values corresponding to variables named `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l`, `m`, `n`, `o`, `p`, `q`, `r`, and `s`.

You get a diagnostic (error message) from the *python interpreter* because none of these variables have been declared.

---

#### The Solution

If you want to create a list of characters you will need to wrap them in `'` or `"` (as in the below).

```
s_count = ['b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s']
```

> <sub>**Note**: Given that the above is very tedious to both write and maintain, a more suitable approach for initializing `s_count` would be `s_count = list ("bcdefghijklmnopqrs")` — which yields the desired result.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you're using undefined variables - `b`, `c`, etc. It seems you meant to use those **characters**, in which case you should surround them in quotes:

```
s_count = ['b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s']
```

Having said that, it's worth remembering that characters are ordinal, so you could just use the `<=` and `>=` operators. Additionally, IMHO, defining a function for this seems like a bit of an overkill when you can just use `sum` and a list comperehension:

```
mystring = 'some string'
strange_count = sum(1 for c in s if c >= 'b' and c <= 's')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can in your case as [Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33058324/2141635) see if each char is >= "b" and < ="s", another efficient approach for specifying certain characters  would be using a set of the chars you want to check for and summing how many times a char from s is int the set:

```
def strange_count(s):
    s = s.lower()
    s_count = {"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"}
    return sum(ch in s_count for ch in s)
```

As far as your error goes you need to actually create strings using double or single quotes:

```
["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"]
```

Using `b,`c`...` python is going to look for variables defined with the names `a,  b,  c....` so you would get a `NameError` unless you actually had those variables defined somewhere.

If you were to use <= then you can could use a simplified chained expression `"b" <= ch <= "s"` with `sum`:

```
def strange_count(s):
    return sum("b" <= ch <= "s" for ch in s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not dealing with very long strings or you are not requested to take in consideration computational costs you can use something like this:

```
input = "Hello world"
input = input.lower()
list_chars = ['b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s']
counts = {}
for c in list_chars:
    counts[c] = input.count(c)

print counts
```